# Beginner JavaScript: using src

Tags: javascript, html, src, low-level

EDIT:[Honestly this works fine you can read my edit comment below.]

So I am very new to JavaScript. This book I have tells me that I can write the script code in another file that has a .js extension. What it doesn't tell me is what should be in that .js extension.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of Document</title>

<script src="path/to/file/fileName.js"></script>  
</head>

<body>
The content of
your page goes here. 
</body>
</html>
```

Lets say I wanted to make an alert message in the java script file. Inside the "fileName.js" would all I write be:

```
alert("This is an alert box");
```

and then save it and call it quits? Cause that is what I have so far and nothing doing.

EDIT:

Ok I want to add this in for anyone in trouble like I was. Turns out, this works perfectly. The comments below are a great help for further information. But the thing I did not realize was that on my Mac I needed to start the path to file at /Users. I feel dumb but at least I figured it out. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: `”` is not a valid quotation mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally your js files will have objects and Methods that are called/used from you main page.
So you html wiil look like :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of Document</title>

        <script src="path/to/file/fileName.js"></script>  
    </head>

    <body onload="showAlert();">
        The content of
        your page goes here. 
    </body>
</html>
```

and you js will look like:

```
function showAlert(){
    alert("This is an alert box");
}
```

Comment: Say it wasnt an alert box and I didn't want it to be on load. Where or how could I use the function then?

Comment: When do you want it to run your function?

Comment: When ever I want. Is it possible to call it anywhere in the body outside of the <> before the </>

Comment: The function can be called from any event, when you click, mouseover, mouseout, on a timer, the possibilities are endless. If you tell me more about what you are doing I can point you in the right direction. ;)

Comment: For these purposes say I had some text in the body and I wanted to load that first and then call this function.

Comment: Never mind, it already did that. Lol I just got it working. I was entering the path wrong. I needed /Users before my computer name. But thank you for your help!

Comment: oh lol i didnt know the check mark would only go one place. dont worry, you win. :D

Answer (score 4):

Use `"` instead of `”`:

```
<script src="path/to/file/fileName.js"></script>
            ^                        ^
```

Comment: Sorry, I already had that. It was some weird formatting thing. still a no go.

Answer (score 1):

Look into events and listeners. For example, if you want the alert to come up when the page loads, your html file would have:

```
<body onload="functionName()">

</body>
```

And you javascript file would have:

```
function functionName() {
    alert("alert message");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would write your Javascript code as a series of functions that you can call whenever you need. So yes, you can write a single statement the way you did but most times its functions.